# Yii2 Abnormal behavior - update div via ajax call with a jui tab widget of a render ajax action

Tags: yii2

Good day folks,

I am having an issue with Yii2, dunno whats goin on after searching online haven't found an answer.

Updated Question with more details

Here is a summary I am trying to change div content of my view via an ajax call to a controller action – the controller action I am calling does nothing but renders another view file which contains a Jui Tab.
The problem is it loads the home page + my Content at a lower part not processed.
If I visit the URL of the action that the ajax request calls, it displays properly with no issues – When I try to append it to my div on another view, this problem occurs.

Here are screenshots of my view

Page Displaying correctly on visiting URL

https://www.dropbox.com/s/77ovpl6fnznjs1p/Page%20displaying%20correctly%20on%20visiting%20URL.png?dl=0

Updating div with the rendered view displays content in a wrong manner

https://www.dropbox.com/s/6nld4wk1p9pkhz9/Screenshot%20of%20the%20update%20view.png?dl=0

---

A-  Initial View Code
Here is my first view code – Contains a div that you click to fireup the ajax call and another div called content which gets the response

brense.PHP

```
<?php
use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\jui\Tabs;
?> <div style="background: blue; cursor: pointer; width:100px;" id="brense">Click ME</div><div id="content">Content</div>
```

- B-    Ajax (JS File) `$('#brense').click(function(){

  ```
     alert('click Received');
      $.ajax({
      url:'index.php?r=assignments/get-me2',
  Type:'GET',
  success:function(data){
   alert("bombo");
      $('#content').append('<div>Appended Content</div>');
      $('#content').html(data);
  }      
  });
  ```

  });
  `

---

C- Controller Action – Called by Ajax

```
public function actionGetMe2(){
         return $this->renderAjax('tab');
     }
```

---

D- Tab’s View that should be loaded inside the div content

```
 <?php

 use yii\helpers\Html;
 use yii\jui\Tabs;

 ?>
  <div>
   <?php echo Tabs::widget(
      ['items'=>[
                ['label'=>'One','content'=>'Content 1'], 
                ['label'=>'Two  ','content'=>'Content 2'],
               ],
      ]
     );
  ?>
 </div>
```

Comment: I may be tired... but I cannot follow you. Why not use Firebug or a developer toolbar to see what gets loaded with Ajax.

Comment: Thanks for trying to help Mihai.
Here is a summary I am trying to change div content of my view via an ajax call to a controller action – the controller action I am calling does nothing but renders another view file which contains a Jui Tab.
The problem is it loads the home page + my Content at a lower part not processed.
If I visit the URL of the action that the ajax request calls, it displays properly with no issues – When I try to append it to my div on another view, this problem occurs. Here is my view

Comment: Did you take a look at the firebug calls, are the calls as you expect, I mean to that exact controller etc?

Comment: yes I had a look - here is a screenshot with the response. I have also updated the question with more details. so OK infront of call status 200 - detailed response of my call > https://www.dropbox.com/s/473uw2atg75uivr/response%20of%20my%20ajax%20call%20Firebug.png?dl=0

Comment: you have quite a few requests. First thing first, when rendering the tags you should not use a layout. You are bringing jquery with your ajax calls back, that might mess things up. Just bring back the actual HTML, no jquery calls.

Comment: So renderAjax() gets rid of layout, I changed my code slightly since my post, rendered widget in initial view and used Ajax to alter data inside widget. This is not ideal because the widget is part of a drill down view that gets filled with an array of model objects. I only want to render the widget on click. I checked page source, jquery seems to be loaded again in renderAjax view, any idea how to get rid of it as you said it may be causing a mess? Thanks

Comment: Try renderPartial not renderAjax, I think renderPartial does not render any js files.

Comment: I tried render partial but it didn't display it properly. May be I should manually add the required files on renderpartial. Will give it a try. Anyway, thanks alot for your support! Cheers!

Comment: If it does not display properly when you access it directly that means it is doing the right thing. Remember that it should just have html content without any css and JS.

Comment: The problem is it doesn't work on the final view either. I even tried to use renderPartial after adding use yii/jui/tabs; and manualling creating the widget on final view page, to make sure css and js gets loaded on final view. I also tried render() with custom layout that gave me a more granular level of control on js and css to be loaded. I think for js to work on elements post loaded after initial page render is complete, we use On(), not sure if this could be the root cause. May be I should report this issue on yii2 to get rectified/managed in post RC releases.

Comment: I do not see what you can report mate, this is not an Yii2 issue, you are doing something with your ajax calls that does not work properly.

Comment: 1 more thing, yii is not in RC state anymore, did you update to the latest version? You may try that first.

Comment: will check if I have the latest yii2 version. I think I have downloaded it some time in November. What I am not sure about is whether or not it is possible to update a div element with another view containing either a jui widget or gridView via Ajax with yii2. In yii 1 it was possible, not sure if this can be done in Yii2. I read that they removed the cclient helpers from Yii2 and I used to rely on them. This is what I wanted to ask about/report if not working as it should. Cheers

Comment: So to make this constructive, try copying a pasting the code in your environment if u have got a couple of mins and let me know if u manage to produce the right outcome. If you did not manage to get this done, we may need to consult those who wrote the framework and provide an answers for those who will read this in the future. Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

Ok, here is the problem. Yii and Yii2 have an automatic numbering of elements. It has elements that are called w0, w1, w2. In a normal page you have w0 1 time, Yii takes care of that. Because you bring in code with Ajax, the page is actually a new page, so it has it's own w0 element. if you take a look at the code that it has it calls

```
$('#w0').tabs();
```

Now that works fine when you look at the page alone, but it will not work ok at all on your page because after inserting the content on the page you have 2 w0 elements. It basically calls the tab on the first one of them (in my test it was the nav bar) and that messes it up. The solution is to give the tabs an id.

So your tab.php file should be:

```
<?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\jui\Tabs;

?>
<div>
    <?php echo Tabs::widget(
        [
            'id' => 'tabs',
            'items'=>[
            ['label'=>'One','content'=>'Content 1'],
            ['label'=>'Two  ','content'=>'Content 2'],
        ],
        ]
    );
    ?>
</div>
```

This should solve your problem, but you migth have other problems too. Like loading jquery and jquery ui 2 times, 1 with the main page the other with your ajax. Now STOP using renderAjax you should use renderPartial.

Your code should be: in the main view file:

```
<?php
use yii\jui\JuiAsset;
JuiAsset::register($this);
?>

    <div style="background: blue; cursor: pointer; width:100px;" id="brense">Click ME</div><div id="content">Content</div>

<?php
$script = <<<EOD
$('#brense').click(function(){
   alert('click Received');
    $.ajax({
        url:'index.php?r=site/get-me2',
        Type:'GET',
        dataType: 'html',
        success:function(data){
            $('#content').html(data);
            $('#tabs').tabs();
        }
    });
});

EOD;
$this->registerJs($script);
```

I am registering jquerui ui asset at the top, if you already have it loaded it will not load it again. I have a function that brings over the ajax, and that function also calls $('#tabs').tabs(); to actually create the jquery ui tabs.

Your controller

```
public function actionGetMe2(){
    return $this->renderPartial('tab');
}
```

Comment: Accept the answer so others may know.